# NLTK Grammar Parsing Error ValueError: Unable to parse line 24

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, grammar

I'm working through Natural Language Processing with Python – Analyzing Text with the Natural Language Toolkit and I'm on chapter 10, Exercise 1:

```
    >Select three or four contiguous sentences from a book for children. A possible source of examples >are the collections of stories in nltk.corpus.gutenberg: bryant-stories.txt, burgess->busterbrown.txt and edgeworth-parents.txt. Develop a grammar which will allow your sentences to be 
    >translated into first order logic, and build a model which will allow those translations to be >checked for truth or falsity.
```

I'm trying to work with the following sentences in the burgess-busterbrown.txt corpus:

```
    >Little Joe Otter was in a terrible rage. It was a bad beginning for a
    >beautiful day and Little Joe knew it. But who wouldn't be in a rage if
    >his breakfast was taken from him just as he was about to eat it? Anyway,
    >that is what Little Joe told Billy Mink.
```

with the following fcfg grammar file & parsing code:

```
    % start S
    S[SEM=(?vp + '(' + ?nps + ',' + ?npo + ')')] -> CONJ[SEM=?conj] NP[SEM=?nps] VP[SEM=?vp] NP[SEM=?npo]
    S[SEM=(?vp + '(' + ?nps + ')')] -> CONJ[SEM=?conj] NP[SEM=?nps] VP[SEM=?vp] AdvP[SEM=?advp]
    S[SEM=(?vp + '(' + ?nps + ',' + ?npo + ')')] -> NP[SEM=?nps] VP[SEM=?vp] NP[SEM=?npo]
    S[SEM=(?vp + '(' + ?nps + ',' + ?s + ')')] -> CONJ[SEM=?conj] NP[SEM=?nps] VP[SEM=?vp] S[SEM=?s]
    S[SEM=(?vp + '(' + ?nps + ',' + ?s + ')')] -> NP[SEM=?nps] VP[SEM=?vp] S[SEM=?s]
    S[SEM=(?vp + '(boy)')] -> P[SEM=?p] VP[SEM=?vp] AdvP[SEM=?advp]
    S[SEM=(?vp + '(boy,' + ?np +')')] -> P[SEM=?p] VP[SEM=?vp] NP[SEM=?np]
    S[SEM=(?s1 + ?conj + ?s2)] -> S[SEM=?s1] CONJ[SEM=?conj] S[SEM=?s2]
    S[SEM=(?vp + '(' + ?np + ')')] -> AdvP[SEM=?advp] AdvP[SEM=?advp] VP[SEM=?vp] NP[SEM=?np]
    
    VP[SEM=?v] -> V[SEM=?v]
    VP[SEM=?v] -> Aux[SEM=?aux] V[SEM=?v]
    NP[SEM=?n] -> N[SEM=?n]
    NP[SEM=?n] -> DET[SEM=?det] N[SEM=?n]
    NP[SEM=?n] -> DET[SEM=?det] Adj[SEM=?adj] N[SEM=?n]
    
    AdvP[SEM=''] -> P[SEM=?p] P[SEM=?p] NP[SEM=?np]
    AdvP[SEM=''] -> Adv[SEM=?adv]
    
    
    CONJ[SEM='&'] -> 'and'
    CONJ[SEM='->'] -> 'So'
    P[SEM=?p] -> 'a' | 'for' | 'wouldn't' | 'if' | 'from' | 'as' | 'to' |'Anyway'
    Adv[SEM=''] -> 'about'
    Adv[SEM=''] -> 'just'
    Adv[SEM=''] -> 'that'
    Adj[SEM=''] -> 'little'
    Adj[SEM=''] -> 'terrible'
    Adj[SEM=''] -> 'bad'
    Adj[SEM=''] -> 'beautiful'
    DET[SEM=''] -> 'a' | 'the'
    N[SEM='Joe'] -> 'Joe' | 'he' |'Otter' |'him' | 'his'
    N[SEM='Billy'] -> 'Bilyu' |'Mink'
    N[SEM='rage'] -> 'rage'
    N[SEM='beginning'] -> 'beginning'
    N[SEM='day'] -> 'day'
    N[SEM='breakfast'] -> 'breakfast' | 'it'
    V[SEM='be'] -> 'was' | 'be'
    V[SEM='in'] -> 'in'
    V[SEM='knew'] -> 'knew'
    V[SEM='take'] -> 'taken'
    V[SEM='eat'] -> 'eat'
    V[SEM='tell'] -> 'told'


    parser = load_parser('grammar_test.fcfg')
    sentence = 'Little Joe Otter was in a terrible rage'
    tokens = sentence.split()
    trees = list(parser.parse(tokens))
    for tree in trees:
       print (tree.label()['SEM'])
```

I get the following error:

```
    > ValueError: Unable to parse line 24: P[SEM=?p] -> 'a' | 'for' | 'wouldn't' | 'if' | 'from' | >'as' | 'to' |'Anyway' Unterminated string
```

Admittedly, I'm not very good at understanding the grammar portion and I adapted parts of the grammar file from others for the same question using different sentences. What am I doing wrong or missing? How do I get it do properly get into the first order logic? I've tried other versions of a grammar, but they gave "Grammar does not cover some of the input words" errors, which feels closer than the above error, but either way, neither worked.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: you have `'` inside `'wouldn't'` and maybe this makes problem. Maybe it needs `'wouldn\'t'` or something else.

Comment: I tried using the \ for 'escaping' that extra ' but that didn't work. Are there other methods for escaping that?

Comment: do you get the same error? maybe now you have different problem

Comment: in Python you can also put text in `" "` when it has `'` - `"wouldn't"` - but I don't know how it works in gramars data.

Comment: I get the same result with  the \. I haven't seen any grammar examples with double quotes, so unsure of who that works with the parsing.

Comment: simply use it to test it - you are the only person which has access to full code, so only you can test it.

Comment: maybe first remove `'wouldn't'` to test rest of code.

Comment: I ended up removing the n't completely....while this may skew the grammar itself, it at least runs. Thanks for walking through

Comment: I tested your code - If I use `"wouldn't"` then it loads parser without problem. Later it show other problem - with word `Little` - but this is different problem

Comment: Yes, that's where I've gotten too. I think its really odd, since "Little" is explicitly in the grammar file and appropriately labeled as an adjective. I've tried some different quotation combos on that to no avail

Comment: you have `little` in grammar but text has `Little`. If I put `Little` in grammar then all works - and this has nothing to do with quotation.